# rspec, autotest and Rails 3 beta 2 can't find executable issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest

I am running Rails 3 Beta2 and attempting to get Autotest working with rspec.

When I run autospec, I receive the following message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:334:in `bin_path': can't find executable autospec for rspec-2.0.0.beta.5 (Gem::Exception) from /usr/local/bin/autospec:19
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.1 with the following Gems:

rails (3.0.0.beta2)
railties (3.0.0.beta2)
rspec (2.0.0.beta.5)
rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.5)
rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.5)
rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.5)
rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.5)
ZenTest (4.3.1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post sorted me out: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/03/15/rspec-2-and-autotest/

autospec is deprecated in favour of autotest with some extra config.

In "./autotest/discover.rb" in the root of the project simply add:

```
Autotest.add_discovery { "rspec2" }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an issue for rspec.
Autospec requires a binary file so that it'd know what to do.
In rspec 1.3.0, [there's one](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/bin/autospec).

In rspec 2.0.0, there's no bin directory so no autospec file.

Answer (score 0):

With rspec2 autotest should be run with `autotest` instead of `autospec`